# Trying to use PugJS to iterate both href attribute and link text

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm having a hard time taking my json object and using the name and values to make a link. I've tried separate arrays as well, but I've decided it'd be easier if I set the object as {title:url} and when I use this code:

```
      ul
    each url, title in news
      li= title
      li= url
```

it returns my titles and urls like so

- These are the arguments against net neutrality — and why they’re
  wrong
- https : //techcrunch .
  com/2017/05/19/these-are-the-arguments-against-net-neutrality-and-why-theyre-wrong/
- The bizarre naming trends that modern startups follow
- https: //techcrunch .
  com/2017/05/20/the-bizarre-naming-trends-that-modern-startups-follow/
- Salesforce marches steadily toward $10B run rate goal
- https :// techcrunch .
  com/2017/05/19/salesforce-marches-steadily-toward-10b-run-rate-goal/
- Uber threatened to fire engineer at center of Waymo trade secret
  lawsuit
- https :
  //techcrunch.com/2017/05/19/uber-waymo-anthony-levandowski-termination-threat/

but when I try to make links with this code

```
   each url, title in news
    a(href= url) title
```

I get this:

```
titletitletitletitle
```

the links work, but it won't iterate the title...
any tips with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to switch to an array and it seems like you need a = after (href= link) like this:

```
   each articles in news
    p
      a(href = articles.url)= articles.title
      li= articles.description
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually that there must be an equal sign (you were right about that) but there can be no space between the assignee (left side) and that equal sign. For example, this works:

```
ul
   each url, title in {'/a': 'Title A', '/b': 'Title B'}
      li
         a(href=url)= title
```

... and will render:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href='/a'>Title A</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href='/b'>Title B</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

If you omit the equals sign or leave a space like this:

```
ul
   each url, title in {'/a': 'Title A', '/b': 'Title B'}
      li
         a(href=url) = title
```

... you'll get:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href='/a'>title</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href='/b'>title</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```